# PHPUnit test for method that sends email once

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, mocking, symfony4

I am trying to write some unit test where I can check if creator of a post  should not receive same email twice.

I am new at testing (not new in Symfony.) I tried some basic test and they work.

First of the problem is that this is a method inside of and DataPersister class within Api Platform which is called everytime entity is persisted and it sends an email to a user..

```
final class EmailDataPersister 
{
   public function persist($data, array $context = [])
   {
    $result = $this->decorated->persist($data, $context);

    if (
        $data instanceof User&& (
            ($context['collection_operation_name'] ?? null) === 'post')
    ) {
        $this->sendEmail($data);
    }

    return $result;
}
    private function sendEmail(User $user)
    {
        $email = (new EmailNotification())
            ->setTitle('Hello ' . $user->getName())
            ->setFrom('sender@sent.com')
            ->setAddress($user->getEmail)
            ->setBody('This is a new email');
        $this->messageBus->dispatch($email);
    }
 }
```

Tried something like:

class someModelTest extends TestCase

```
  public function testEmails()
{
    $this->satEmail('test@pmg.co');

    $this->assertMessageCount(1, 'should have sent one email');

    $msg = $this->getMessages()[0];

    $this->assertArrayHasKey('test@pmg.co', $msg->getTo());
}

public function satEmail($email)
{
    $msg = (new \Swift_Message('Testing..'))
        ->setSubject('Hello')
        ->setBody('Hello')
        ->setFrom('helle@example.com')
        ->setTo($email);

    $this->mailer->send($msg);
}
```

I think I need to add..

```
        $model = $this->getMock('someModel', array('setFrom', 'setTo', 'setSubject', 'send'));
        $controller->expects($this->once())
            ->method('setFrom');
        $controller->expects($this->once())
            ->method('setTo');
        $controller->expects($this->once())
            ->method('setSubject');
        $controller->expects($this->once())
            ->method('send');
        $model->sendEmail();
    }
```

I can not figure out should I call that method inside the class or what should I define model controller etc?

Comment: What's the subject you want to test? `EmailDataPersister`? I see a `messageBus` property, but in your test you are mocking a `Swift_Mailer`. How is it determined whether an e-mail has already been sent?

Comment: Yes, I want to test method inside EmailDataPersister. I want to get to the point where test is checking that the mail is not sent to the same user twice. Also the first part of the test runs succesfully. @PhilipWeinke

Comment: Ok. But `sendEmail` is just the method that sends the mail. Where's the logic that handles whether an email should be sent? The Data Persister has public methods like `persist` and `remove`, right? Do you want to test any of these methods? Maybe you could share the rest of your `EmailDataPersister` class.

Comment: Yes that is right. I updated the post. I didn't know there should be any other part of code that handles whether an email should be sent.. @PhilipWeinke